# Submitting VWAP or Arrival Price orders in IBPy

Tags: ibpy

does anyone have any advice / experience on how to submitting VWAP or Arrival Price orders in IBPy? I am familiar with how to submit limit orders, but would like to start using more sophisticated order types.
Thanks!

Comment: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/apiguide/tables/ibalgo_parameters.htm#XREF_70690_Arrival_Price    Plenty of examples, just translate to python.

Comment: Yes, I cannot figure out how to incorporate e.g., 'm_algoParams.add( new TagValue("maxPctVol","0.01") )'; Can you offer some insight into how to incorporate these additional required parameters?